# Can't load image in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, laravel-blade

i'm newbie in laravel

I'm just succesfully upload an image and store name in database.
linkd 'public' folder to 'storage/App/public' also but can't show it on the page.
image is also on that folder with protected random name.
I can't load image with that url also 'http://localhost:8000/storage/flower.jpg'.
what should i do now ????

web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::post('/update/{id}','HomeController@update')->name('update');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

HomeContoller.php

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){

       $student = user::find($id);

       if ($file = $request->file('profile_image')) {
           $file = $request->file('profile_image');
           $request->file('profile_image')->store('public/');
           $img_nm = $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalName();

           $student->image = $img_nm;
       }

         $student->username = $request ->username;
         $student->first_name = $request ->first_name;
         $student->last_name = $request ->last_name;
         $student->gender = $request ->gender;
         $student->email = $request ->email;
         $student -> save();
         return redirect()->route('home');

 }
```

home.blade.php

```
<td>
  <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$student-> image) }}"/>
</td>
```

fileSystems.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: sir I have updated my code. Please help me out. If need more ask me. Thanks

Comment: _"linkd 'public' folder to 'storage/App/public'"_ Are you using symlinks? Note that to use links - you need `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` for your project `<Directory>` in your apache site config.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<img src="storage/"{{$student-> image}}/>
```

Comment: sir i have tried more code like that and used yours also. Sorry it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The upload method is wrong, if the original filename is needed then, use the `storeAs` function,

`$file = $request->file('profile_image');`

```
$img_nm = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->storeAs('images', $img_nm);
$student->image = $img_nm;
```

Refer https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads

And in your blade file, use this

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/images/'.$student->image)}}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir i use your method but didn't succeed. I can save image name in DB succeesfully. but can't show it in the page. that's the main problem